# datatables not fetching any data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to fill a datatable with some info from the database ... but it doesn't work the table is just empty even thou I am calling the data from the database .

this is the controller function i am using :

```
public function CP()
{
    $res = Entreprise::join('secteurs','secteurs.id','=','entreprises.secteurs_id')
                         ->select('entreprises.RS as RS' , 'secteurs.libelle as secteur' , 'entreprises.Tel1 as tel',);
    $data = ['LoggedAdminInfo'=>admin::where('id' , '=' , session('LoggedAdmin'))->first()];
    return view('admin.admin_panel' , $data ,[ 'resultas'=>$res ]);
}
```

and this is the table :

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <table id="datatable" class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>RS</th>
        <th>Secteur</th>
        <th>Telephone</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   @foreach($resultas as $resultat)
   <tr>
       <td>{{ $resultat->RS}}</td>
       <td>{{ $resultat->secteur}}</td>
       <td>{{ $resultat->tel}}</td>
   </tr>
   @endforeach
</tbody>
```

and the route I am using :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['AdminCheck']], function(){
Route::get('/CP', 'App\Http\Controllers\SiteController@CP') ->name('CP');

});
```

please if you have any idea why is it not working !!

Comment: what return ``dd($res)``?

Comment: @ZiaYamin it returns this :


Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {#310 ▼
  #query: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder {#303 ▶}
  #model: App\Models\entreprise {#312 ▶}
  #eagerLoad: []
  #localMacros: []
  #onDelete: null
  #passthru: array:19 [▶]
  #scopes: []
  #removedScopes: []
}

Comment: try my answer, copy and paste

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: @ZiaYamin yes but it didn't work

Comment: does it have any error?

Comment: no errors  just empty table

Comment: add ``dd($res = Entreprise::join('secteurs','secteurs.id','=','entreprises.secteurs_id')
                         ->select('entreprises.RS as RS' , 'secteurs.libelle as secteur' , 'entreprises.Tel1 as tel',);->get())`` to your code.

Comment: dd()  returns the data i want

Comment: so there should not be any proble

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the problem was something silly ... i was missing ->get() in the end of my query, this is the correct code :

```
public function CP()
{
    $res = Entreprise::join('secteurs','secteurs.id','=','entreprises.secteurs_id')
                     ->select('entreprises.RS as RS' , 'secteurs.libelle as secteur' , 'entreprises.Tel1 as tel',)->get();
$data = ['LoggedAdminInfo'=>admin::where('id' , '=' , session('LoggedAdmin'))->first()];
return view('admin.admin_panel' , $data ,[ 'resultas'=>$res ]);
}
```

Comment: if you check my answer I have added this one. I said that copy my code and paste it

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass data that want to use in blade as array at 2nd parameter in [view](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views) function.

Update your code to

```
public function CP()
{
    $res = Entreprise::join('secteurs','secteurs.id','=','entreprises.secteurs_id')
                         ->select('entreprises.RS as RS' , 'secteurs.libelle as secteur' , 'entreprises.Tel1 as tel',);
    $data = [
         'LoggedAdminInfo' => admin::where('id' , '=' , session('LoggedAdmin'))->first(),
         'resultas' => $res
    ];
    return view('admin.admin_panel' , $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function CP()
{
     $resultas=Entreprise::join('secteurs','secteurs.id','=','entreprises.secteurs_id')
            ->select('entreprises.RS as RS' , 'secteurs.libelle as secteur' , 'entreprises.Tel1 as tel')->get();
            
    $LoggedAdminInfo = admin::where('id' , '=' , session('LoggedAdmin'))->first();
    return view('admin.admin_panel' , compact('resultas', 'LoggedAdminInfo'));
}
```

and in your view file you can get the same variable that you passed in compact() method.

```
@foreach($resultas as $resultat)
   <tr>
       <td>{{ $resultat->RS}}</td>
       <td>{{ $resultat->secteur}}</td>
       <td>{{ $resultat->tel}}</td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: What is it saying..? which version of laravel are you using

Comment: no errors just empty table ... i have the last version of laravel

Comment: OK , leave dynamic data try to catch static data.  $static_data = 'Static Data'; return view('admin.admin_panel' , compact('static_data'));  now try to print it.

Comment: Maybe , data is not coming from database... so try to catch static data.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
public function CP()
{
     $resultas = Entreprise::join('secteurs','secteurs.id','=','entreprises.secteurs_id')
                     ->select('entreprises.RS as RS' , 'secteurs.libelle as secteur' , 'entreprises.Tel1 as tel')->get();
     $data = ['LoggedAdminInfo'=>admin::where('id' , '=' , session('LoggedAdmin'))->first()];
return view('admin.admin_panel' ,compact('data','resultas') );
}
```